# Laravel 4: remember() results from ::all()

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4

Is it possible to apply the `remember(60)` function to something like `Service::all()`?

This is a data set that will rarely change. I've attempted several variations with no success:

- `Service::all()->remember(60);`
- `Service::all()->remember(60)->get();`
- `(Service::all())->remember(60);`

Of course, I am aware of other caching methods available, but I prefer the cleanliness of this method if available.

Comment: An odd quirk to keep in mind (see my answer below), but in retrospect I guess it makes sense ;) ... Also, I recommend checking out the docs linked to below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to simply swap the two such as

Change

```
Service::get()->remember(60);
```

to

```
Service::remember(60)->get();
```

An odd quirk I agree, but after I ran into this a few weeks back and realized all I had to do was put `remember($time_to_remember)` in front of the rest of the query builder it works like a charm.

For your perusing pleasure: See the [Laravel 4 Query Builder Docs Here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html#881-893)

```
/**
  * Indicate that the query results should be cached.
  *
  * @param  int  $minutes
  * @param  string  $key
  * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
  */

 public function remember($minutes, $key = null)
 {
     list($this->cacheMinutes, $this->cacheKey) = array($minutes, $key);
     return $this;
 }
```

[L4 Docs - Queries](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)